# execute system with perl variable

Tags: perl, system

I want to execute a bash command inside perl script. I know how to do this, BUT, when I try to save the command in a variable and then execute it... I have problems.

This is working inside my perl script perfectly:

```
system("samtools", "sort", $file, "01_sorted.SNP");
```

This is not working and I would like to know WHY, and HOW to fix...:

```
my $cmd = "samtools sort $file 01_sorted.SNP";
print "$cmd\n";  # Prints the correct command BUT...
system($cmd);
```

ERROR:

```
open: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have an injection error in the latter snippet. By that, I mean that when you built your shell command, you forgot to convert the value of `$file` into a shell literal that produces the value of `$file`. That's quite a mouthful, so I'll illustrate what that means below.

---

Say `$file` contains `a b.txt`.

```
my @cmd = ("samtools", "sort", $file, "01_sorted.SNP");
system(@cmd);
```

is equivalent to

```
system("samtools", "sort", "a b.txt", "01_sorted.SNP");
```

This executes `samtools`, and passing the three strings `sort`, `a b.txt` and `01_sorted.SNP` to it as arguments.

---

```
my $cmd = "samtools sort $file 01_sorted.SNP";
system($cmd);
```

is equivalent to

```
system("samtools sort a b.txt 01_sorted.SNP");
```

This executes the shell, passing the string as a command to execute.

In turn, the shell will execute `samtools`, passing the *four* strings `sort`, `a`, `b.txt` and `01_sorted.SNP` to it as arguments.

`samtools` can't find file `a`, so it gives an error.

---

If you need to build a shell command, use [`String::ShellQuote`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote).

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
my $cmd = shell_quote("samtools", "sort", "a b.txt", "01_sorted.SNP");
system($cmd);
```

is equivalent to

```
system("samtools sort 'a b.txt' 01_sorted.SNP");
```

This executes the shell, passing the string as a command to execute.

In turn, the shell will execute `samtools`, passing the three strings `sort`, `a b.txt` and `01_sorted.SNP` to it as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The error `open: No such file or directory` does not look like an error printed by perl as `system` will not print any error for you. That's probably printed by `samtools`, so just check that your filenames—`$file` and `01_sorted.SNP`—are correct and the files exist. Also, if `$file` contains spaces, put its name into quotes in the command line. Or, even better, use `system(@args)` as suggested in comments.

If you have no ideas, run your script using `strace`:

```
strace -f -o strace.log perl yourscript.pl
```

and check `strace.log` to see on which `open` call it fails.